# Is it possible for a queryset filter to not work properly? Django 1.11.12

Tags: django

I ran the code below... and somehow... I got a couple of campaigns that were not active and were passed into the update_existing_campaigns. I am a little mindblown as to how this happened... it was also only a couple of inactive campaigns that were passed in, not all of them. How is this possible?

```
all_campaigns = AdCampaign.objects.all()
active_campaigns = AdCampaign.objects.filter(active=True)
update_existing_campaigns(active_campaigns)



def update_existing_campaigns(active_campaigns):
        # only update active campaigns that haven't already been run today. used to handle failures in middle of job
        active_campaigns_to_update = active_campaigns.filter(last_auto_update__lt=datetime.date.today())

        for active_campaign in active_campaigns_to_update:
             # do something
```

Comment: Try it in your shell, see what happens. `python manage.py shell`, then import your models, then see what printing the queryset returns. From something that simple it's hard to believe it's a django bug.

Comment: Showing the `AdCampaign` model in full would be helpful as well!

Comment: Might also be interesting to see what `update_existing_campaigns` is doing.

Comment: @BjörnKristinsson just added the code of what that is doing.